# Cannot find path to opendiff error

Tags: git, bash, version-control

N00b here, needing to know how to find out if I have opendiff installed. If I don't, how do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the Mac OSX Developer tools which shuold have been included on the CD which came with your Mac. I believe you can also download it from the Apple Developers Site after registration.

Once it is installed you'll find it in **/usr/bin/opendiff**

Answer (score 0):

opendiff is a command line tool.  So, you should be able to open a terminal, then type `opendiff -h`.  If it's installed, you should see a help file.  If not, you'll get a 'opendiff: command not found' error message.  I think opendiff is part of Mac OS X - I don't know that you can get it outside that.

Comment: If you're not wedded to some specific feature of opendiff, maybe GNU 'diff' will serve your needs?